# Specific way to compute QR factorization of a product of matricies

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix $A\colon\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that is invertible. And then I have $m < n$ and an injective matrix $B\colon \mathbb{R}^{m}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I want to compute the QR factorization of $AB$ from the decomposition of $A$ into $Q_{A}$ and $R_{A}$ and $B$ into $Q_{B}$ and $R_{B}$. In particular, I would like to avoid recomputing the QR decomposition on matrices derived from $A$ i.e $Q_{A}$ and $R_{A}$ (e.g. as is done in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1174583/how-to-compute-qr-decomposition-of-a-product-of-matrices)).

Honestly, for my purposes, the specifics of the QR factorization don't matter - I would be happy with a procedure like this that simply found a matrix $Q_{AB}$ that is orthogonal times some other matrix $R_{AB}$ that is invertible and $m$ by $m$ with the obvious $AB=Q_{AB}R_{AB}$.

Edit: I realize what I actually just want is an orthogonal basis for the range of $AB$ with computing any factorizations on anything deried from A.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but using the QR decomposition on both matrices might get you closer to what you're looking for (using [the rectangular QR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition)).

Your first matrix $\mathbf{A}$ gets mapped to two matrices $\mathbf{R}_\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{Q}_\mathbf{A}$ as $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{Q}_\mathbf{A}\mathbf{R}_\mathbf{A}$ where $\mathbf{Q}_\mathbf{A}$ is orthogonal.

Similarly, applying QR to the rectangular matrix $\mathbf{B}$ requires taking its transpose (we need to have more rows than columns).

We can factorize

$$ \mathbf{B}^\mathsf{T} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{Q}_1 & \mathbf{Q}_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{R}_1 \\ \mathbf{0}\end{bmatrix}$$
where $\mathbf{R}_1$ is $m\times m$ upper-triangular, and $\mathbf{Q}_1$ is $n\times m$.

Hence
$$\mathbf{B}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{A}^\mathsf{T} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{Q}_1 & \mathbf{Q}_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{R}_1 \\ \mathbf{0}\end{bmatrix} \mathbf{R}_\mathbf{A}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{Q}_\mathbf{A}^\mathsf{T}
$$

which gives

$$\mathbf{AB} = \mathbf{Q}_\mathbf{A}\mathbf{R}_\mathbf{A}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{R}_1^\mathsf{T} & \mathbf{0}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{Q}_1^\mathsf{T} \\ \mathbf{Q}_2^\mathsf{T}\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{Q}_\mathbf{A}\mathbf{R}_\mathbf{A}\mathbf{R}_1^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{Q}_1^\mathsf{T}$$

Comment: WHile this is related, I think this is not quite what I want because I want $Q_{AB}$ to be an orthogonal basis from the range of $AB$, which I can't read off this. But, it looks like I would get a basis for the range of $B^{T}A^{T}$, which is a very good point.

Comment: Unless $Q_{A}R_{A}R_{1}^{T}$ is somehow orthogonal?

Comment: But that can't be ebcause $AB$ need not be.

Comment: I think the trick is this: $Q_{2}^{T}A^{T}$ gets you the null space of $(AB)^{T}$. This is the orthogonal complement of the range of $AB$. So I think we can use that, but I need to think about it.